# Создание правил перенаправления с помощью .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, php

Как при помощи htaccess можно сделать следующее:
Все запросы к к директории, скажем, directory обрабатывает скрипт по адресу

```
directory/get.php
```

А в адресной строке встаёт адрес

```
directory/строка_запроса
```

Вот как этого добиться можно?

Comment: а что то такого вида

    RewriteRule ^directory/(.*) directory/get.php?q=$1

q - это параметр, скрипт то должен как то получить строку.

Comment: @KoVadim Я нифига не понял, так что более реально поясню.
Запрос типа faq/answer123 , get.php должен получить это как get.php?answer123, число будет меняься, естественно. Урл должен оставаться как answer123

Comment: @KoVadim И еще бы хотелось узнать, шде можно достать подробную литературу по этому делу

Comment: а можно более аккуратно со словами? мы же не на улице.

    RewriteRule ^faq/(.*)=(\d+)$ get.php?$1$2

почитать - начните [здесь](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Правда там на аглийском... но гугл точно подскажет, где и на русском найти.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил свою задачу так:
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^answer([0-9]+)/? get.php?answer=$1 [L]